# Apache and MySQL is running but "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/" is showing "This webpage is not available"

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL and APache running in my PC . Here is the screenshot .

[image]

But "127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/" link is showing the error "This webpage is not available" .  Here is the screenshot .

[image]

But I do not understand why . I have searched a lot in internet to solve this problem but cant solve this . How can I solve this ?

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but is PHPMyAdmnin installed? You did not mention that above.

Comment: i have alreaddy installed phpMyadmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Apache config shows that ports are 8080 and 443
(look at the image, near Apache under column Ports

so use this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin/
```